# How can i clear all the cookies from particular domain in expressjs using res.clearCookie()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can I clear all the cookies for a particular domain say `awesomedomain.co` using `res.clearCookie()`.
 I  tried `res.clearCookie('cookie_name',{path:'/',domain:'.awesomedomain.co'})` 
But this clears only cookie with  `cookie_name`.
I want clear all the cookies from the domain name, i.e `awesomedomain.co`

Comment: true but this could be used by all javascript developers in their application, not particularly react.

Comment: Oh ok..done, thanks

Comment: `.awesomedomain.co` this will clear cooking for its subdomains , remove `.` and try.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari: my bad, there was editing mistake. I want to clear all the cookies for the domain. Your solution would clear only that one particular cookie and not all.

Answer (score 1):

One of the working solution is to loop through all and delete

```
const cookies = req.cookies;

for (let prop in cookies) {   
  res.clearCookie(prop); //Or res.cookie(prop, '', {expires: new Date(0)});
}
```